# Group and limit for multiple groups

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchdb-futon

I have the following documents

```
{
  "_id": "id",
  "_rev": "123456",
  "author": "john",
  "views": "3",
},
{
  "_id": "id",
  "_rev": "123456",
  "author": "jake",
  "views": "5",
},
{
  "_id": "id",
  "_rev": "123456",
  "author": "jake",
  "views": "6",
},
{
  "_id": "id",
  "_rev": "123456",
  "author": "john",
  "views": "1",
},
{
  "_id": "id",
  "_rev": "123456",
  "author": "jake",
  "views": "7",
},
{
  "_id": "id",
  "_rev": "123456",
  "author": "john",
  "views": "10",
}
```

Lets suppose that these are comments and I would like to get the 2 most viewed comments by user.

How can I do that in CouchDB?

In any other sql database I could perform 2 queries with `limit 2` and then merge the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an array with that data in JavaScript you can simply use the sort method:

```
var a = [{...}, {...}, {...}];

a.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.views - a.views;
});

console.log(a[0]) //{ "_id": "id", "_rev": "123456", "author": "john", "views": "10" }         
console.log(a[1]) //{ "_id": "id", "_rev": "123456", "author": "jake", "views": "7" }
```

---

If you want to only have the to most viewed records you can use the [slice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var a = [...];
a.sort(...);

a = a.slice(0, 2);
```

Comment: Yes that's correct but what about the 2 most viewed? Not only one.

Comment: @salamis As you can see the arr `a` is sorted in a way that the most viewed is the first item and the second to most viewed is the second item. So `a[0]=most viewed` & `a[1]=second to most viewed`

Comment: Hm.. thanks.. You are right. The question now is if this is the optimal way to do it in CouchDB..

Comment: Well, getting all the data from the DB to client and processing it with JS is certainly not the most efficient method ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could just use this `map`:

```
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.author, -doc.views], null);
}
```

without the reduce. Query with options `?startkey=['john']&limit=2` should result with something like:

```
{"total_rows":5,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"id1","key":["john",-10],"value":null},
{"id":"id2","key":["john",-3],"value":null}
]}
```

Note the `-` sign when emitting `doc.view` to get biggest view count. You can also use `descending=true` option, but it will also reverse the order of the author string. This is not natural order for strings and you might need that in the future ;)